# Jquery/Javascript thumbnail image problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, padding, margin

I have several thumbnail images that are spaced (with margin) 5 pixels apart in html list tags.  I also have Jquery listeners for their mouseenter and mouseleave events that update a parent image according to whichever thumbnail is being rolled over.

If you scroll from one thumbnail image to another, the transition is not smooth.  When the mouse is in the 5 pixel spacing, the parent image jumps quickly to its default value then back to the next thumbnail when the cursor moves over it.

How can I make this smooth so it goes from image to image without jumping back to default parent image.

I've tried making the spacing as padding, but the design has a border around the images and this makes it look bad.

Thanks!

EDIT. - > code request

```
$image_changer = $('.imageChanger');
$image_changer.each(function(){
$(this).mouseenter(function(){
    $backup_old_image = $('.product-img-box .product-image img').attr('src');
    $('.product-img-box .product-image img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
});
$image_changer.mouseleave(function(){
    $('.product-img-box .product-image img').attr('src', $backup_old_image);
});
```

Example on product page..
http://www.greencupboards.com/loyal-luxe-the-canadian-cabin-15706.html

Comment: We will need an example and/or code.

Comment: would you mind sharing your current code? without that we have no clue how to answer this

Comment: I didn't think the code would help much, but there it is I hope its useful!

Answer (score 1):

use a wrapper or place the padding and mouseover event triggers on the li element

```
<li style="padding:5px">
   <img href="content.png" alt="content">
</li>
```

```
$("li").hover(function(){},function(){})
```

#### Edit

After seeing the site:

change

```
#main-content .more-views ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

to

```
#main-content .more-views ul li {
  padding-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

and get rid of the margin-right on the images.

then change the jQuery to

```
$image_changer = jQuery('.more-views li');
$image_changer.each(function(){
jQuery(this).mouseenter(function(){
    $backup_old_image = jQuery('.product-img-box .product-image img').attr('src');
    jQuery('.product-img-box .product-image img').attr('src', jQuery(this).find("img").attr('src'));
});
});
$image_changer.mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery('.product-img-box .product-image img').attr('src', $backup_old_image);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried something similar AND your implementation and it doesn't seem to access the image through jquery.  The rollover doesn't work at all now.  I've tried it in jsfiddle and it works, I can't figure out what might be conflicting.  I've even tried giving the li items a class and accessing that, but that didn't work either